# Navigate Open/Save As dialog with keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if someone knows some tricks for navigating Open and Save As dialogues with the keyboard in Windows 10.

I know some general shortcuts. However, when I try to navigate these dialogues with the keyboard I have to use a lot the Tab key.

Also, for my web explorer, I use an add-in called Vimium, is there something similar for windows to make it easier to navigate with the keyboard?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such product.

You could create your own shortcuts per each of these dialogs by using the free
macro product [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The possibilities using AutoHotkey are basically unlimited, but require some
learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

In the file explorer, you can press the first letter of the file to jump to it and cycle through files of the same first letter. It's easier than drill-clicking tab. Like @harrymc said, you could use a hotkey application, but Windows has this as a built-in feature.

Comment: I think the OP is wanting to go up/down the folder tree, navigate to quick access/favourites/documents, filename dialog etc... rather than finding a specific file in the given folder. This is why they say they have to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to navigate.

Comment: Tab goes down the file list, right? By typing in the first letter, it jumps to that specific file or folder. They could navigate quickly based on that.

Comment: Yes, but I believe the OP wants to tab to other parts of the dialogue, not just the file selection, although I may be wrong.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. In that sort of scenario I would try just typing the filename into the dialogue using the whole thing like "C:\fakepath\item.extension." If OP can use a mouse that would help, but I'm assuming they're limited to keyboard only.